# missing script: start Electron

Tags: angularjs, npm, electron

I try to create my first angular application using Electron, so i follow this guide here :

[Electron Documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)

so i do step by step what is in the guide but when i do this command :

```
npm start
```

I get this error here:

```
$ npm start
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\FreeLancer\angular2electron\npm-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2electron",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "my first angularjs",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "LAIDANI Youcef",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Someone have an idea about this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: @corn3lius i edit my question, you can check my `package.json`

Comment: `npm test` will run the command in the `scipts.test`. `npm start` will run the command you put in the `scripts.start`

Comment: the electron quick start https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/package.json has the start script as `electron .`

Comment: oooh it work very good, thank you @corn3lius so much :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`npm start` runs the script in the package.json. To get an electron app running with it just add `electron .` to the start script :

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "angular2electron",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "my first angularjs",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
    "start" : "electron ."
  },
  "author": "LAIDANI Youcef",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```